# VSTS Release Management for .NET Core

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm using VSTS 2017 Release Management with a build-once-deploy-many-strategy. My project is a dotnet core-webproject. First I restore/build/test/publish my project with `dotnet` and then I publish my artifact (a zip).

[image: My build steps]

Now I want to deploy **this build** with **different configurations** to **different environments**. With "regular" dotnet I used WinRM Web App Management together with a [parameters.xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398068(v=vs.110).aspx) to add my environment-specific configuration. As example below:

[image]

But my package created with `dotnet publish` is a zip and not a msdeploy-package.

1. How do I replace the configurations (appsettings.json)?
2. How can I deploy it to my IIS?

**What I've already tried:**

First I ran `dotnet publish` but without the *Zip Published Projects*-option. This made it possible to easily make my changes i `appsettings.json`, but instead required me to use a *Copy file*-operation to do my deploy. This had the downside of IIS locking the files, which in turn required me to write PS-scripts which took IIS offline/online.

I just want to create a package, which can be deployed to several environments and with different configurations. How can I achieve it?

Comment: How about Azure Key Vault? Does it meet your requirement?

Comment: @starain-MSFT - I'm certain it would work great. But unfortunately I cannot use any cloud services in my current project. And we don't have Azure on-premise either.

Comment: You also can encrypt sensitive information and use it in appsettings.json, then decrypt in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to change `appsettings.json`. The core project can retrieve data from `appsettings.[environment].json` file per to **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** environment variable.

So, just set the **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** environment variable in each environment machine only once.

A related thread: [VSTS Deploy IIS App winrm and change appsettings.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45202133/vsts-deploy-iis-app-winrm-and-change-appsettings-json).

Update:

Regarding sensitive connectionstring, the better way is protecting secrets using **Azure Key Vault**. A blog about how to use it: [Protecting Secrets using VSTS and Azure Key Vault](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/najib/2017/03/07/protecting-secrets-using-vsts-and-azure-key-vault/).

You also can encrypt sensitive information (e.g. connectionstring), then decrypt in your code.

Another way is that you can replace the value before build the project (e.g. Visual Studio Build task) in VSTS build/release. Note: if others can access the published artifact or get the build source file (e.g. private build agent), they can get the sensitive information **regardless of replacing the value before build or storing in parameters.xml**.

Comment: We already use appsettings.x.json. But then I assume we need to have the settings in source control?

Comment: Also, as a follow-up-question, how do I handle __aspnetcore_environement__ if there are several environments on the same server?

Comment: @smoksnes Not clear about settings in source control, what settings? Regarding in same server, no, just a environment in a server. But, you can set environment by using [WebHostBuilder.UseEnvironment method](https://andrewlock.net/how-to-use-multiple-hosting-environments-on-the-same-machine-in-asp-net-core/). (Update the code before build task (e.g. [Replace Tokens task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens))

Comment: Sorry. With settings I mean my appsettings.json. Let's say that we have a sensitive connectionstring that might not be suitable to have in source control. With the suggested solution I figure that all these must be in source control and known at compile-time?

Comment: @smoksnes The better way is protecting it using Azure Key Vault, check the update of my reply.